# How to align bars right in position_dodge with preserve = 'single'?

Tags: r, ggplot2

When creating a bar chart with grouped data and using `position_dodge(preserve = 'single')` each bar has a "natural" position; however `geom_col` seems to left-align the bars. For example, in the code below the leftmost bar appears with a big gap before the next group. I would have expected that firs bar to be right-aligned. What is a good way to achieve this?

(One possible solution is to add some zero-height bars, I suppose.)

```
library(tidyverse)

crossing(year = 2013:2023, qtr = 1:4) |> 
  slice(-(1:3)) |> 
  mutate(y = 1:n()) |> 
  ggplot(aes(year, y, fill = factor(qtr))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single'))
```

[image]

Comment: Try using `position_dodge2(preserve = "single")`.

Comment: Using `position_dodge2` makes a small difference but essentially the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `complete()` will introduce `NA` wherever there's a "missing" row (*ie* a missing combination of `year` and `qtr`). Plotting this will cause `position_dodge(preserve = 'single')` to work as you'd like.

```r
library(tidyverse)


crossing(year = 2013:2023, qtr = 1:4) |> 
  slice(-(1:3)) |> 
  mutate(y = 1:n()) %>%
  complete(year, qtr) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, y, fill = factor(qtr))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single'))
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (`geom_col()`).
```

[image]

Comment: This is the similar to what I had in mind with "One possible solution is to add some zero-height bars, I suppose" (i.e., `complete(year, qtr, fill = list(y=0))` which adds zeros instead of NAs).

Comment: Yes. Conceptually an advantage to keeping NA is nothing gets drawn. If your actual data has bars around 0, or if true measurements could yield ~0, it is arguably better to not fill with a value. If the real data is at all like the toy you provided, however, its likely safe to fill with zeroes.